# Displaying from multiple table based on the time and showing the source table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So, for example, I have 3 tables

Table 1: **name**

```
id | name | time
 1 | Bob  | 20.42
```

Table 2: **item**

```
id | item   | time
 1 | Bottle | 18.42
 2 | Box    | 21.42
```

Table 3: **food**

```
id | Food | time
1 | Steak | 19.42
```

So I want to display them like this

```
From table item: 1 | Bottle
From table food: 1 | Steak
From table name: 1 | Bob
From table item: 2 | Box
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
select id, name
from (
    select * from name
    union all
    select * from item
    union all
    select * from food ) t
order by t.`time`
```

Comment: ...or something like that.

Comment: The superquery's not strictly necessary.

Comment: how do I display the source?

Comment: @user8043784 That question has been addressed elsewhere.

Comment: @Strawberry If results do not need `time` column, maybe super query is necessary. Don't play petty tricks please. :-)

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me :-s

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry and sorry, you've scared me :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS name;

CREATE TABLE name
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,time TIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO name VALUES
(1,'Bob','20:42:00');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item;

CREATE TABLE item
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,item VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,time TIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO item VALUES
(1,'Bottle','18:42:00'),
(2,'Box','21:42:00');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS food;

CREATE TABLE food 
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,food VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,time TIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO food VALUES
(1,'Steak','19:42');

SELECT *, 'name' source FROM name
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'item' FROM item
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'food' FROM food
ORDER BY time;
+----+--------+----------+--------+
| id | name   | time     | source |
+----+--------+----------+--------+
|  1 | Bottle | 18:42:00 | item   |
|  1 | Steak  | 19:42:00 | food   |
|  1 | Bob    | 20:42:00 | name   |
|  2 | Box    | 21:42:00 | item   |
+----+--------+----------+--------+
```